# Creating a custom method that can be used on collections in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I've longed used the `.Where({ })` method when working with collections, and I want to create a similar one. But, I can't figure out how it works or how to use `Update-TypeData` to update what methods can be used on collections.

An example of a collection would be `$gci = Get-ChildItem` which outputs "Collection`1" when `$gci.GetType().Name` is used.

I've made custom methods for the String type before, but creating a method for the collections 'container' seems to be substantially more difficult.

What I would consider a solution is pointing me toward what the `-TypeName` parameter for `Update-TypeData` should even be.